# Validación inicio de sesión

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un formulario para validar un inicio de sesión ingresando correo electronico y contraseña, se supone que al darle click en el input value="Iniciar Sesión" se debería ejecutar y redireccionarme o generarme la alerta de que el correo electrónico o la clave están mal, sin embargo, no se en que estoy fallando ya que no funciona y no me redirecciona o aparece la alerta ,no se ejecuta ni el if ni el else, no se si es la función o algún error de sintaxis.

Este es el HTML:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="login-design">
      <div class="waves">
      </div>
      <div class="login">
        <div class="login-data">  
          <h1>Inicio de sesión</h1>
          <form action="#" class="login-form">
            <div class="input-group">
              <label class="input-fill">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                <span class="input-label">Correo Electrónico</span>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i> <br />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <label class="input-fill">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                <span class="input-label">Contraseña</span>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
              </label>
            </div>
            <a href="#">¿Necesitas una cuenta?</a> <br /> <br /> 
            <input value="login" class="btn-login" type="submit" id="login" onclick="ingresar()">
          </form>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </main>
</body>
</html>```

Este es el JS:

```function ingresar(){

        var email = (document.getElementById('email')).value;
        var password = (document.getElementById('password')).value;

        if(email == 'estefany-44@hotmail.com' && password == '1a'){
  
            window.location.href = "https://admission.laboratoria.la/cohorts/reg-2022-05- 
            admission-js-reg001/topics/admission-js/03-learning-mindset/01-welcome-and-objectives"
        }
        else{
            alert('Revise clave o correo')
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Hola @Estefpania. Efectivamente es un error de sintaxis.

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir el js en donde está la función o dejar la función js dentro de un script

Comment: espera y lo analizo

Comment: Hola, como así editar la pregunta? y añadir el js en donde está la función o dejar la función js dentro de un script ? no entendi ya que tengo el html aparte del javascript

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: vale gracias @Weizman

Comment: Si no estoy mal en la función te hace falta recibir un parametro e y lo primero que hagas es e.preventDefault();

Comment: asi?

function ingresar(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = (document.getElementById('email')).value;
        var password = (document.getElementById('password')).value;

        if(email == 'estefany-44@hotmail.com' && password == '1a'){
  
            window.location.href = "https://admission.laboratoria.la/cohorts/reg-2022-05-admission-js-reg001/topics/admission-js/03-learning-mindset/01-welcome-and-objectives"
        }
        else{
            alert('Revise clave o usuario')
        }
    }

Comment: correcto, el e.preventDefault() hace que no se refresque la página

Comment: no me funciona :( se sigue refrescando y no me redirecciona

Comment: Prueba con e.target.preventDefault(), y asegúrate que están siendo recibidos los valores con un console.log(email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

respondiendo a tu pregunta

```js
document.getElementById('btn-login').addEventListener("click", e => ingresar(e))
        const ingresar = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
            var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
            if (email == 'estefany-44@hotmail.com' && password == '1a') {
                alert("login correctodf")
                window.location.href = "https://admission.laboratoria.la/cohorts/reg-2022-05-admission-js-reg001/topics/admission-js/03-learning-mindset/01-welcome-and-objectives"
            }
            else {
                alert('Revise clave o correo')
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
    <main class="login-design">
        <div class="waves">
        </div>
        <div class="login">
            <div class="login-data">
                <h1>Inicio de sesión</h1>
                <form class="login-form">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label class="input-fill">
                            <input type="email" required name="email" id="email">
                            <span class="input-label">Correo Electrónico</span>
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i> <br />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label class="input-fill">
                            <input type="password" required name="password" id="password">
                            <span class="input-label">Contraseña</span>
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">¿Necesitas una cuenta?</a> <br /> <br />
                    <button type="submit" id="btn-login">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <!-- el script va antes de finalizar el body. Aquí iria la referencia-->
    <script> </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Lo conseguí generándole al botón un actionListener() para que al presionar llamar la función de ingresar a la cuál como te mensionaba le puse un `e.preventDefault();` para que no refrescara la página. Lo demás está bien.

Comment: dejame lo pruebo y te aviso

Comment: function ingresar(e){

    document.getElementById('btn-login').addEventListener("click", e => ingresar(e));
        const ingresar = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
            var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
            if (email == 'estefany-44@hotmail.com' && password == '1a') {
                alert("login correctodf");
            }
            else {
                alert('Revise clave o correo');
            }
        }
    }     asi?

Comment: claro. Supongo que te funcionó, verdad? Quedo atengo

Comment: no :( lo tengo así tal cual, lo hiciste aquí o en algún editor de codigo?

Comment: Por cierto, el input de submit lo cambié por un boton y le agregué un id

Comment: si lo note, lo deje asi: button type="submit" id="btn-login">Login</button>
tal cual lo dejaste tu pero creo que ya se cual es el error ya te aviso

Comment: es estraño, aquí le doy ejecutar y funciona. Si quieres copia el codigo tal cual en el form que tienes

Comment: si, tal vez estoy haciendo algo mal pero no he cambiado nada mas, solo pusiste el boton y generaste document.getElementById('btn-login').addEventListener("click", e => ingresar(e)) ya ahi viene la funcion definida no tengo que volver a definirla arriba

Comment: No hace referencia a ella mediante el id del boton que tiene un oyente que al presionar click ejecuta la función

Comment: Ya funciono! Te agradezco muchísimo por la paciencia y la ayuda, saludos!

Comment: Vale, por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada. Un saludo

Comment: listo ya quedo gracias